# Docker File Secrets stored in RAM?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have a PHP application which reads the database config from a file named "database.php". Now, in the production server, I am planning to pass this **database.php as a secret file**.

My question is whether my PHP application will read the secret file(database.php) as a normal file(because it is not in file storage, but in RAM), or if the read will be slower as the container has to request the secret from SWARM Manager.

A similar example is in docker docs where they have passed index.html as a secret file. -> [link to docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#simple-example-use-secrets-in-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is whether my PHP application will read the secret
>   file(database.php) as a normal file(because it is not in file storage,
>   but in RAM)

Yes, to the PHP application this will appear as a normal file, it does not need any extra handling.

> or if the read will be slower as the container has to request the
>   secret from SWARM Manager.

The read will not be any slower, since the secret will be mounted (and thus copied into memory), and this will be done only once.

Comment: Thanks that clears my concern. It seems like this is the best way to pass the DB config file. There is no example over the internet where they have passed a 'code' file(.php here) as secret, which is why I was doubtful.